# Copying an attachment from one Custom List to another using a workflow

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, custom-list, attachments

My initial requirement is to have column level permission in a custom list.(Set of users can see the column and set users cannot).

Since SharePoint doesn't support column level permission i have tried to use a workaround with two custom lists.
One with the specified column ie:CusList_A and another without the column ie:CusList_B.

Then i created a workflow for CusList_A. I designed the workflow in a away that,
when a new item is added to the CusList_A the workflow will create a new item in CusList_B with the values of CusList_A.

The problem is that CusList_A have a coulmn for an attachment. Standard settings of the workflow doesn't allow me to get the attachment from CusList_A and to set it as the attachment of CusList_B.

**How can i get an attachment from one custom list and to put it in another custom list using a workflow?**

*I am using sharepoint online 2013 and sharepoint designer 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attachments in a custom list cannot be copied in SP2013.
What you can do is to create a document library and use the copy document task when creating the workflow.
You can create a document library with the columns you only want to show to a particular set of users and set the permissions of that doc library only for those users.
And in the workflow when a user adds an item use the copy document function and copy that item/document into another document library with all the columns (with the columns you don't want to show to those previous set of users).